# Spring boot application with apache axis

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, axis

I am trying to run a spring boot jar which has axis2 dependencies in it. I am using spring boot maven plugin to build the jar (with dependencies). When I try to run my jar, I get the following exception in my console:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The G:application\myapp\target\myapp.jar!\lib\axis2-1.6.1.jar file cannot be found.
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.setClassLoader(DeploymentFileData.java:111)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:70)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.loadClassPathModules(RepositoryListener.java:222)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:71)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:64)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadFromClassPath(DeploymentEngine.java:175)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:135)
at ...
```

I then checked the structure of my jar. It has lib folder inside it, which contained all the jars (including the above mentioned axis jar). Attached is the screen shot of lib folder[image].
Following are the solutions which I have tried:

1. Placed axis jar in the same directory as application jar.
2. Created lib folder in the same directory as application jar and placed axis jar inside it.
3. Modified manifest file to include Class-Path: /lib/

None of the solutions has worked. However, when I run the application class in eclipse, the app starts and runs perfectly. But, once I create the jar, nothing seems to run.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: spring-boot-loader modules allow applications to load classes from nested jars, which is very cool, but it seems axis2 tries to 'deploy' the jar on it's own, I'm not sure what that means, and can't find it. you might have to provide the jar externally

Comment: How to provide the jar manually? I already tried including it in classpath but it didn't work :(

Comment: can you package it as a war file and deploy it on external tomcat?

Comment: I don't have tomcat installed and don't think it is possible to install it on server. We have to rely on spring boot tomcat plugin only :(

Comment: hm, there must be something wrong with how you put the jar on the classpath

Comment: when you run it in eclipse it's done the same way basically so it has to be possible after packaging into a jar and externalizing the nested one

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like Axis can't cope with being run from a jar that's nested within another jar. It works fine in Eclipse as the Axis jar is available directly on the filesystem rather than being nested inside your Spring Boot application's jar file.

You can configure your application's fat jar file so that Spring Boot knows to unpack the Axis jar into a temporary location when it's run. If you're using Maven:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <requiresUnpack>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </requiresUnpack>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And if you're using Gradle:

```
springBoot  {
    requiresUnpack = ['org.apache.axis2:axis2']
}
```

See the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-extract-specific-libraries-when-an-executable-jar-runs) for some further details.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. It worked once I made these changes. The generated exception wasn't informative and hence, I never knew something like this could be the reason behind this. Even apache don't state that you can't execute axis from inside a jar(but why would they?).
Alternatively, I managed to make it work by using maven shade plugin without knowing this reason (I guess shade plugin works because it extracts all the jars into classes). Anyway, thanks again for the answer.