# Spring Boot Application With Axis2 - /BOOT-INF/lib/addressing-1.6.2.mar file cannot be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-axis, axis

During SOAP call am getting a below exception, but in local am not getting any exceptions.

I am really not sure why addressing-1.6.2.mar referring application jar path.

**Axis2 Structure:**

[image]

**VM Arguments:**

```
JAVA_HOME=/apps/jdk/jdk1.8.0_111

ANTIFRAUD_HOME=/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev

nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java-Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dspring.config.location=file:$ANTIFRAUD_HOME/properties/application.properties -Dlogging.config=file:$ANTIFRAUD_HOME/properties/log4j2.xml -Djava.security.auth.login.config=file:$ANTIFRAUD_HOME/properties/kafka-client-jaas.conf -DConfigPath=$ANTIFRAUD_HOME/hasbroResources -Daxis2.repo=$ANTIFRAUD_HOME/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository -Daxis2.xml=$ANTIFRAUD_HOME/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/conf/axis2.xml  -jar $ANTIFRAUD_HOME/lib/a-notification-0.0.1.jar &
```

**Exceptions:**

```
2019-01-31T08:09:04.603-0600 INFO Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/mex-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.603-0600 INFO Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/mex-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.610-0600 INFO Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/mtompolicy-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.611-0600 INFO Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/mtompolicy-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.642-0600 INFO Deploying module: ping-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/ping-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.645-0600 INFO Deploying module: ping-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/ping-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.663-0600 INFO Deploying module: script-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/scripting-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.663-0600 INFO Deploying module: script-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/scripting-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.674-0600 INFO Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/soapmonitor-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.677-0600 INFO Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/soapmonitor-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.794-0600 INFO Deploying module: rampart-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/rampart-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.794-0600 INFO Deploying module: rampart-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/rampart-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.814-0600 INFO Deploying module: addressing-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/addressing-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.814-0600 INFO Deploying module: addressing-1.6.2 - file:/apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/hasbroResources/resources/axis2/repository/modules/addressing-1.6.2.mar
2019-01-31T08:09:04.821-0600 ERROR The addressing-1.6.2.mar module, which is not valid, caused The /apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/lib/antifraud-notification-0.0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/addressing-1.6.2.mar file cannot be found.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The /apps/Benefits/AntiFraud/r20/dev/lib/antifraud-notification-0.0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/addressing-1.6.2.mar file cannot be found.
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.setClassLoader(DeploymentFileData.java:111) ~[axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:70) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.loadClassPathModules(RepositoryListener.java:222) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:71) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:64) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:158) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:133) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:151) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:144) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at com.aonhewitt.hro.benefits.emplmgmt.services.EmployerMgmtStub.<init>(EmployerMgmtStub.java:207) [EmployerMgmt-1.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.aonhewitt.hro.benefits.emplmgmt.services.EmployerMgmtStub.<init>(EmployerMgmtStub.java:193) [EmployerMgmt-1.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.aonhewitt.hro.benefits.emplmgmt.services.EmployerMgmtStub.<init>(EmployerMgmtStub.java:242) [EmployerMgmt-1.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.alight.anti.fraud.hasbro.client.EmployerMgmt.getClientStub(EmployerMgmt.java:126) [classes!/:0.0.1]
    at com.aonhewitt.hasbro.webservice.service.HasbroBaseService.createClientStub(HasbroBaseService.java:130) [hasbro-webservice-util-1.0.jar!/:?]
```

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213372/spring-boot-application-with-apache-axis . Axis requires unpacked jars to locate the classes. Not sure why this jar is read from classpath and rest all jars are read from file system.

Comment: can you push sample project to github, it'll be more helpful

Comment: It would be useful to have the project's build file (ie: pom.xml) as well.