# Spring boot 2.2.6 application with apache axis Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-axis

My question is similar to this one ([Spring boot application with apache axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213372/spring-boot-application-with-apache-axis)) but I am running Spring Boot v2.2.6.  When I execute the command

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get the error

```
2021-06-01 00:41:53,152 myjar [http-nio-9090-exec-1] ERROR 
org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer - deploy:94 - The addressing-1.6.3-classpath- 
module.jar module, which is not valid, caused The /Users/xxxx/workspace/myjar/build/libs/myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/addressing-1.6.3-classpath- 
module.jar file cannot be found.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The /Users/xxxx/workspace/.../build/libs/myjar-0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/addressing-1.6.3-classpath-module.jar file cannot be found.
```

I also have the relevant build.gradle snippet

```
api "org.apache.axis2:addressing:1.6.3:classpath-module"
api "org.apache.axis2:axis2:1.6.3"
api "org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb:1.6.3"
api "org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-local:1.6.3"
api "org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-http:1.6.3"
```

I confirmed that the file /Users/xxxx/workspace/myjar/build/libs/myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/addressing-1.6.3-classpath-module.jar does exist.  Can anyone help fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Axis cannot cope with one jar file being nested inside another. For situations like this, you can [configure Spring Boot to automatically unpack the nested jar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-unpacking) when you start your application:

```
bootJar {
    requiresUnpack '**/addressing-*-classpath-module.jar'
}
```

Comment: Thx.  That did it!